# Using variable in exact match regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that I want to exact-match.

The code I have so far:

```
<?php

$string = "Such asinine comments such as";
$findStr = "such as";

$result = preg_match("/[\b$findStr\b]/i", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
//$result = preg_replace("/^$findStr$/i", "such&#160;as", $string);
echo $result;
echo "Offset = ".$offset."\n";
var_dump($result);
var_dump($matches);

?>
```

The output I get:

```
1Offset = 
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) " "
    [1]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```

What can I do to get an exact match?
So far, I have tried the following regexes:
`/\b[$findStr]\b/i`
`/^$findStr$/i`
`#$findStr#i`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `preg_match('\b/' . preg_quote($findStr) . '\b/', $string ... )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put the pattern inside a character class.

```
preg_match("~\b".$findStr."\b~i", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
```

OR

I think the problem is only with the `[]` character class. The below works fine for me. And note that whenever a variable is used inside a regex, you must enclose the pattern or regex within double quotes not with single quotes. Because single quotes won't expand the variables.

```
preg_match("~\b$findStr\b~i", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
```

Answer (score 5):

For an exact match, you don't need a regular expression. You can use strpos()

```
$pos = strpos($string, $findStr);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position might be the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    //string not found
} else {
    //string found at position $pos
}
```

Comment: It's faster than using "preg_match", but the OP requested a RegExp solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$string = 'Test Case';
$search_term = 'Test';
if(preg_match("~\b" . $search_term . "\b~", $string)){
  echo "Matched";
} else {
  echo "No match";
}
?>
```